# If there exists an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $A = Y \bigcap U$ then $A $ is open in $Y$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $Y$ be subspace of a metric space $X$. Show that $A \subset Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if there exists an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $A = Y \bigcap U$.

My Try: Let $A$ be open in $Y$. Then for each $a \in A$, there exist $r_a$ such that $B(x,r_a) \subset A$ and then taking union of such open ball over each point will lead us to an open set say $B$ in $X$ such that $A = Y \bigcap U$.

But how to prove the other direction that if there exists an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $A = Y \bigcap U$ then $A $ is open in $Y$ ??

Please Help!!

Comment: It comes from that $U \cap Y$ is an open in $Y$ for the induced topology. For all point $x\in U$, there exist an open ball $B$ that stay in $U$ (in the big space X). Now $B\cap Y$ is an open ball in $Y$ that stay in $Y \cap U$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but you may be able to use some of these facts about intersections being open:

If we have two open sets $A_{\alpha_{1}}$,$A_{\alpha_{2}}$, their intersection is open. If the intersection is empty, then it is open since the empty set is open. If the intersection is not empty there is some $x\in A_{\alpha_{1}} \bigcap A_{\alpha_{2}}$. Since $A_{\alpha_{1}}$,$A_{\alpha_{2}}$ are open, there is some $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ such that $V_{1} \subset A_{\alpha_{1}}$ and $V_{2} \subset A_{\alpha_{2}}$. We can choose some $V = min(V_{1},V_{2})$ then $V \subset A_{\alpha_{1}} \bigcap A_{\alpha_{2}}$.

Finite Intersections are open. Suppose $B$ is a finite intersection and $x\in B$ where $B = A_{\alpha_{1}}\bigcap A_{\alpha_{2}} \bigcap \ldots \bigcap A_{\alpha_{n}} \Rightarrow x\in A_{\alpha_{i}}$, $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$. Since each $A_{\alpha_{i}}$ is open, there is an open set $V_{i}\subset A_{\alpha_{i}}$ for each $i$ such that $x\in V_{i}\subset A_{\alpha_{i}}$, $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$. Then $x\in \bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}V_{i}\subset B$ and $\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}V_{i}$ is open $\Rightarrow B$ is open.

Countable Intersections are not open.
Example: $A_{n} = (-1 - \frac{1}{n},1 + \frac{1}{n})$ is open $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{n} A_{n} = [-1,1]$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between balls with in $X$ versus balls in $Y$. Let's do so by an index to $B$. So to repeat your argument for one direction more precisely: Let $A$ be open in $Y$. then for each $a\in A$, there exists $r_a>0$ such that $B_Y(x,r_a)\subset A$. Then we can let $U=\bigcup _{a\in A}B_X(a,r_a)$ and find that $A=Y\cap U$. This uses the fact that $B_Y(a,r)=B_X(a,r)\cap Y$.

For the remaining direction, assume $A=Y\cap U$. Then for $A\in A$ there exists $r_a>0$ such that $B_X(a,r_a)\subset U$. But then $B_Y(a,r_a)=B_X(a,r_a)\cap Y\subset A$.

Comment: I've corrected a minor overlooking ($B_Y(a,r) = B_X(a,r)\color{red}{ \cap Y}$) and a typo ;)